# Error Updating GDAL with Homebrew

Tags: gdal, homebrew

I recently updated my version of GDAL using the Homebrew package manager.  However, now whenever I use GDAL from within my terminal shell, I get the following error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libspatialite.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/gdaladdo
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

GDAL commands that are made from within QGIS, however, still work.  (I'm assuming that a path needs to be updated, but have no idea how to proceed).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### The GDAL version of QGIS:

- If you use the QGIS version of [KyngChaos](http://www.kyngchaos.com/) (framework), it uses the version of GDAL which is in:

> /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.9 (or 1.8, 1.10)

and has nothing to do with Homebrew.

- If you want to use the Kyngchaos version of GDAL in the shell:

[image]

- or write in the .bash_profile file in your Home folder:

  > export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH
- If you want to upgrade the GDAL version used by QGIS, use the GDAL update of KyngChaos.
- In addition, you can use in the shell any version of GDAL (1.8, 1.9,1.10) that are in the folder  /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/ simply adjusting the PATH.
- All the Frameworks of Kyngchaos are compiled to to work together. The libspatialite.x.dylib are in /Library/Frameworks/SQLite3.framework/Versions/3/unix/lib and not in /usr/local/lib/ 
  [image]
- So in the same way, you can use spatialite in the shell

[image]

### The GDAL version of Homebrew:

Your problem with Homebrew is that you must also install/upgrade the Spatialite Homebrew version. This is not done automatically as in the Frameworks of William Kyngesburye.

That's why I always use these frameworks (for not having n versions of GDAL and Spatialite).