# GDal problem "no suitable image found" when I run “ogr2ogr” command

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr

I am trying to run "ogr2ogr" command

```
macbook$ sudo ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=test user=postgres" /Users/macbook/planning.gdb
```

But I am getting this error:

```
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/GDAL
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/GDAL: not a file
```

I following this answer : 
[Error Updating GDAL with Homebrew](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/63455/error-updating-gdal-with-homebrew)

```
macbook$ export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH
macbook$ which ogr2ogr 
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr

But I am getting this error whenever I run the "ogr2ogr" command 

macbook$ sudo ogr2ogr -f "PostgreSQL" PG:"dbname=test user=postgres" /Users/macbook/planning.gdb
dyld: Library not loaded: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/GDAL
  Referenced from: /Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs/ogr2ogr
  Reason: no suitable image found.  Did find:
    /usr/local/lib/GDAL: not a file
```

When I run : macbook$ ls /usr/local/lib/
I can find the folder :

```
dtrace                  libopencv_highgui.dylib
gcc                 libopencv_imgproc.2.4.6.dylib
gdal                    libopencv_imgproc.2.4.dylib
```

Comment: Have you tried running ogr2ogr without sudo?

Answer (score 1):

You have a problem with your PATHS:

1. with Homebrew,  GDAL is installed in `/usr/local/Cellar` with  symbolic links of the programs (ogr2ogr, etc.) in `/usr/local/bin`
2. with the Frameworks of KyngChaos, the versions of GDAL are installed in `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.x/GDAL` with the programs in `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.x/Programs` (`/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs` is a symbolic link for the version used)

   [image]

The programs of the KyngChaos distribution use the libraries  present in the Framework folder (`/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework)`and not  those present in `/usr/local/lib/GDAL`(for Homebrew).

To verify the correct paths, type in the Console:

```
otool -L ogr2ogr
```

If the result is:

```
ogr2ogr:
/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Versions/1.10/GDAL (compatibility version ...)
```

You are using the GDAL libraries of KyngChaos

If the result is

```
ogr2ogr:
/usr/local/lib/GDAL (compatibility version ...)
    ....
```

You are still using the Homebrew libraries even if if you  type `export PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework/Programs:$PATH`

So you must adapt your paths, look at [Building GDAL 1.9.x with ESRI FileGDB support on OS X Lion](https://gist.github.com/zhm/2005158) for example.