# Installing QGIS using Homebrew

Tags: qgis, python, gdal, mac, homebrew

I've been unsuccessfully trying to install QGIS using Homebrew (used Homebrew to install GDAL and GSL) as outlined [here](http://scottdavey.net/article/Installing-GDAL-and-QGIS-on-OSX-Yosemite-231)

My OS is Mac Yosemite, 10.10.5.
The installation sort of finishes, but with a warning

> Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
>   You can try again using `brew post install osgeo/osgeo4mac/qgis-26`

The app does not start due to lack of compatibility with MacOX system.

I also tried to use the .dmg from http://www.kyngchaos.com, but it does not even open the image complaining that GDAL 1.11 is not installed, when in fact it is.

Any tips, please?

## UPDATE

I tried with qgis28 and still get the following warning during installation:

```
==> Pouring qgis-28-2.8.3.yosemite.bottle.tar.gz

==> defaults delete "/usr/local/Cellar/qgis-28/2.8.3/QGIS.app/Contents/Info.plist" LSEnvironment

==> defaults write "/usr/local/Cellar/qgis-28/2.8.3/QGIS.app/Contents/Info.plist" LSEnvironment "{ 'PATH' = 'home/.rbenv/s
Last 15 lines from home/Library/Logs/Homebrew/qgis-28/02.osgPlugins-3.4.0';:

Warning: The post-install step did not complete successfully
You can try again using `brew postinstall osgeo/osgeo4mac/qgis-28`
*(which upon running returns the very same warning)*

defaults write "/usr/local/Cellar/qgis-28/2.8.3/QGIS.app/Contents/Info.plist" 
LSEnvironment "{ 'PATH' = '(my paths) 'PYTHONPATH' = '/usr/local/Cellar/qgis-28/2.8.3/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages'; 'GDAL_DRIVER_PATH' = '/usr/local/lib/gdalplugins'; 'GRASS_PREFIX' = '/usr/local/opt/grass-64/grass-6.4.4'; 'OSG_LIBRARY_PATH' = '/usr/local/lib/osgPlugins-3.4.0'; }"

Could not parse: { 'PATH' = '(my paths)' } Try single-quoting it.
```

### upon starting qgis

```
Warning: loading of qgis translation failed [/usr/local/Cellar/qgis-28/2.8.3/QGIS.app/Contents/MacOS/../Resources/i18n//qgis_en_US]

Warning: loading of qt translation failed [/usr/local/Cellar/qt/4.8.7_2/translations/qt_en_US]

Warning: QGraphicsScene::addItem: item has already been added to this scene
ERROR 1: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/gdalplugins/gdal_GRASS.so, 1): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/grass-64/grass-6.4.4/lib/libgrass_vect.6.4.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found

ERROR 1: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/gdalplugins/ogr_GRASS.so, 1): Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libgeos-3.4.2.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/grass-64/grass-6.4.4/lib/libgrass_vect.6.4.4.dylib
  Reason: image not found
```

- I have libgeos-3.5.0.dylib, not libgeos-3.4.2.dylib. Where could I change version referencing?
- I have Python2.7 as the system default version and miniconda's Python3.

I did notice confusions between Python versions and GDAL. Unfortunately, have not been able to figure it out yet. When I do `brew link gdal`, it links to Python2.7 and can't use it with IPython3 (obviously...), but when I unlink it, the command line tools (ogr2ogr) does not work.

What am I missing and how to fix the geo-toolkit (GDAL+QGIS working together in peace)?

Comment: Any warning pop-up related to dependencies during the install at any point?

Comment: @whyzar I've included the output above

Answer (score 2):

Mac OS X is an Unix system where the paths and the links are very important and you are mixing two things (look at [QGIS on Mavericks](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/80872/2581), [Error Updating Gdal with Homebrew](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/63475/2581) or [QGIS python location problem](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/56973/2581), for example).

In short, the installation paths and the links are different:

1. Homebrew uses libraries and executables installed in `/usr/local/Cellar` with symbolic links in `/usr/local/bin`
2. The [Kyng Chaos QGIS version](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/qgis)  uses Frameworks installed in `/Library/Frameworks/GDAL.framework` (for example). It is stipulated in the download page

> Requirements: GDAL Complete 1.11 framework package, Matplotlib Python module

Therefore, the compiled QGIS versions of Homebrew and Kyng Chaos use different links and you cannot use the GDAL library installed in `/usr/local/Cellar` with the Kyng Chaos version and vice-versa unless you are a Unix specialist or compile yourself QGIS

These Unix paths allows to use at the same time the Homebrew and Kyng Chaos versions without interferences.

Comment: Thanks @gene. So I focused on 1), thus the QGIS via Homebrew installation attempt. I installes GDAL, GSL, QGIS via Homebrew, and still having version/link problem. Any hints?

Comment: Use the Kyng Chaos version,  it's the easiest to install. There are many versions of Homebrew QGIS  ( [Homebrew/-science:QGIS](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-science/blob/master/qgis.rb), [homebrew-osgeo4mac](https://github.com/OSGeo/homebrew-osgeo4mac), etc.) with problems

Comment: Then I also need  Kyng Chaos versions of GDAL etc, right? And there will be no conflicts with the Homebrew ones? (e.g. using Python gdal pip installed package)

Comment: The Kyng Chaos version uses the Apple Python (in /usr/bin) and the Homebrew version uses the Homebrew Python (in /usr/local/bin)